# How can I use cookies using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager in AFNetworking 2.0+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

As it is known, **AFHTTPSessionManager** in AFNetworking 2.0+ supports cookies.

But is it possible for **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** in AFNetworking 2.0+ to support cookies?

Comment: Have you solved it for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  AFNetworking uses the foundation URL Loading system, which handles cookies out of the box.

You can configure NSMutableURLRequest's `setHTTPShouldHandleCookies` and use `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to store them.

In Objective-C:

```
NSArray *cookieStorage = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:url];
NSDictionary *cookieHeaders = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookieStorage];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [myRequestSerializer requestWith…];
for (NSString *key in cookieHeaders) {
    [request addValue:cookieHeaders[key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
}
```

In Swift:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest() // you can use an AFNetworking Request Serializer to create this

if let cookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookiesForURL(url) {
    for (headerField, cookie) in NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookieStorage) {
        request.addValue(cookie, forHTTPHeaderField: headerField)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you point me toward a method to *clear* cookies? E.G., start a fresh session with the same manager? Thanks.